# Delete content between specific characters in a string

Tags: c#

I have a string value having content like :

```
string samplevalue="1. e40 e51 2. f31 f56 (f16) 3. j40 h51 4. k31 (c18) k56 ";
```

i want to delete characters between "(" and ")" , for example the above string should be like :

```
string samplevalue="1. e40 e51 2. f31 f56 3. j40 h51 4. k31 k56 ";
```

how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Does your string always look like that? can the value inside a parenthesis contain space?

Comment: it can also contains space ex : ( ab12  ) , (ab12), ( ab12)

Comment: Ummm, can the text in the parenthesis repeat? like in your example you have f16 inside a parenthesis, is it possible for f16 to appear somewhere else in the string but not inside a parenthesis?

Comment: How do you get to this point? I.E data from db?, user input? etc... I always find that if you have to do heavy/manual string manipulation, then there is certainly a better way to achieve what your trying to do.

Comment: @crimson589 , yes you are right it is possible

Comment: Have you tried to use regular expression to replace them with an empty text?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on your problem.

```
string samplevalue = "1. e40 e51 2. f31 f56 (f16) 3. j40 h51 4. k31 (c18) k56 ";
string sampleoutput = samplevalue;
MatchCollection matchList = Regex.Matches(samplevalue, @"\(([^)]*)\)");
var list = matchList.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();

foreach (string stringToRemove in list) {
     sampleoutput = sampleoutput.Replace(stringToRemove, "");
}
```

output

`1. e40 e51 2. f31 f56  3. j40 h51 4. k31  k56`

Small thing, my output has an extra space where the remove text used to be, i'm not sure how your spacing works but if you only need 1 space for each there are solutions out there for removing extra whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this, have a look

```
string samplevalue = "1. e40 e51 2. f31 f56 (f16) 3. j40 h51 4. k31 (c18) k56 ", 
       newstring = string.Empty;
bool isstart = false;
foreach (char c in samplevalue)
{
   if (c == '(')
   {
      isstart = true;
   }

   if (isstart)
   {
      if (c == ')')
      { isstart = false; }
   }
   else { newstring += c.ToString(); }

}
```